# How to get space between two <div> in lightning page?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

How to get space between two  in lightning page?

[image: apex]

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">     

            <span><lightning:input label="CustomerID" name="rpaId" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_ID__c}" /></span>
             <br/>          
            <span><lightning:input label="Customer Name" name="customername" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_Name__c}" /></span>
             <br/>            
      </div>      
   <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">              
       <span><lightning:input label="SSN" name="dob" value="{!v.RPABot.SSN__c}" /></span> 
       <br/>              
       <span><lightning:input label="DOB" name="dob" value="{!v.RPABot.DOB__c}" /></span>
       <br/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use padding and margin to get that.

`slds-m-right_small` - you will get right margin of small size
`slds-p-left_large` - you will get left padding of large size.

You can try:

```
<lightning:input label="CustomerID" class="slds-m-right_small" name="rpaId" value="{!v.RPABot.Customer_ID__c}" />
```

Documentation is here: https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/

Answer (score 0):

You better use lighting design system's `<lightning:layoutItem />` under `<lightning:layout />`